# What is the difference between web UIs on 4040 and 8080?

Tags: apache-spark

There are two different web UIs (one is for standalone mode only). Can I use web UI on port 4040 when I am launching Spark in standalone mode? (example:`spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`- web ui 8080 is working, 4040 - not.) What is the main difference between these UIs?

Is it possible for me to launch Spark (without hadoop, hdfs, yarn etc), to keep it up and to submit my jars(classes) into it? I want to watch job statistics after it finishes. I am trying something like this:

```
Server: Spark\bin>spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
Worker: Spark\bin>spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://169.254.8.45:7077 --cores 4 --memory 512M
Submit: Spark\bin>spark-submit.cmd --class demo.TreesSample --master spark://169.254.8.45:7077 file:///E:/spark-demo/target/demo.jar
```

It runs. It gets new WebUI on port 4040 up for this task. I dont see anything in Master's ui on 8080.

Currently I'm using win7 x64, spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6. I can switch into linux if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the web UI port for standalone Master using `spark.master.ui.port` or `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT` as described in [Configuring Ports for Network Security / Standalone mode only](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#standalone-mode-only).

Standalone Master's web UI is a management console of a cluster manager (that happens to be part of Apache Spark, but could've been a separate product as Hadoop YARN and Apache Mesos). Having said that, it can often be confusing what the two web UIs have in common, and the answer is nothing.

The Spark driver's web UI is to show the progress of your computations (jobs, stages, storage for RDD persistence, broadcasts, accumulators) while standalone Master's web UI is to let you know the current state of your "operating environment" (aka the Spark Standalone cluster).

I leave the other part of your question about History server to [@Sumit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584012/1305344).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can launch the Spark as a standalone server, without any Hadoop or HDFS. Also as soon as you submit your job to master, it will show your job either in in-"Running jobs" or "Jobs Completed" section.

You can also enable History Server for preserving the job Statistics and analyzing the same at a later time -

```
./sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

Refer [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) for more details on enabling History server