# Spark shell not executing 'Initial job has not accepted any resources'

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I'm working on AWS EC2 instance where I installed Spark 2.2.0 and I have 8 GB of RAM and 2 cores.

I was following this tutorial to play a little with pyspark shell:
https://sparkour.urizone.net/recipes/managing-clusters/

I started the master and I started one slave worker and they show up on the web ui.

However, in the shell, when I try to execute a command like:

```
>>> tf = spark.sparkContext.textFile('README.md')
>>> tf.count()
```

I get this:

> [Stage 0:>                                                          (0
>   + 0) / 2]
>   17/08/29 11:02:51 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that
>   workers are registered and have sufficient resources

In my spark-env.sh, I set variables like this:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=127.0.0.1
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1000m
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
```

So, I don't know why there is a problem. The pyspark shell doesn't reach the worker slave properly I guess.

Comment: Can you try 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863521/why-does-my-pyspark-just-hang-as-accepted-in-yarn-when-i-launch-it/43225607#43225607 ?

Comment: I modified spark-defaults.conf to add  
'spark.driver.memory              3g' but it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

In this setup I would start spark with settings like this:

`spark-shell (or spark-submit) --master local[*] --driver-memory 4G ...`

From one of my comments:

With such a small machine, I suspect you won't be able to run on cluster mode. The thing is that the spark driver takes resources as well as the two other workers. In this scenario, you have 1 core driver + 2 workers * 1 core . You could try to resize down the number of workers to 1 and that should work.

Comment: when I do it works in standalone mode and it doesn't show up on the cluster web ui not does it stage the work among executors.

Comment: In your comment, you don't say you are running in cluster mode.  So I guessed you were running a single EC2 instance in standalone mode.

Comment: yes I'm running on a single EC2 instance in standalone mode. But when I do --master local[*], the app doesn't show up at all on 127.0.0.1:8080 web UI.

Comment: You should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579822/what-is-the-difference-between-web-uis-on-4040-and-8080

When in standalone mode, you should consult localhost:4040

Comment: With such a small machine, I suspect you won't be able to run on cluster mode.  The thing is that the spark driver takes resources as well as the two other workers.  In this scenario, you have 1 core driver + 2 workers * 1 core .  You could try to resize down the number of workers to 1 and that should work.  As I suggested, you should run in standalone mode with this small machine as you will waste less resources.

Comment: yes @michel-lemay this actually solved the problem. Setting 1 worker with 2 cores and 2GB or 2 workers with 2G and 1 core each solved the issue.

Comment: Can you edit your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? After all the commandline parameters where not the issue.